# Why am I getting the "Conversion failed" error in SQL Server 2012 even though my parameter type is varchar?

Tags: sql-server

Pretty much all stated in the title. I have a stored procedure with some input parameters that I execute and save as an object. Here is the declaration of the input parameters:

```
@As_Document_NAME VARCHAR(50) = NULL,
@As_Company_NAME VARCHAR(50) = NULL, 
@As_Category_NAME VARCHAR(50) = NULL,
@As_Project_NAME VARCHAR(30) = NULL,
@As_Employee_Last_NAME VARCHAR(30) = NULL,
@As_Employee_First_NAME VARCHAR(30) = NULL,
@Ai_Employee_Ssn_NUMB INT = 0,
@As_Tag_TEXT VARCHAR(2000) = NULL,
@Ad_Start_DATE DATE = NULL,
@Ad_End_DATE DATE = NULL
```

However, when I try to execute the stored procedure like this:

```
EXEC EDOC_RETRIEVE_S2 '','','','','','',0,'pls,I,cant','',''
```

I get the error

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'pls,I,cant' to data type int.

What can I do to fix this? I checked and my parameters in the execution statement and the parameter declaration are all in the exact same order.

Comment: The problem then comes from when you use the parameter on your sp

Comment: What is the body of the procedure doing with it? BTW, you can (and arguably should) reference your parameters by name when calling a procedure. That way you don't to ensure they are in the same order. (@As_Document_NAME = '', etc..)

Comment: It looks like your pointer is off by one.  So what it thinks is param 7 is actually param 8.  You should change them all to VARCHARs just one time, and check the output.

Comment: @Lamak Yes you're right, this ended up being the problem. In one line of my stored proc, I was treating the parameter as an integer value. Thanks!